# IPP printing from Windows Server 2016 fails to complete

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer

I'm trying to get Windows Server 2016 to print to IPP connected printer but Windows is having trouble getting everything to work fully.

When I add the printer, it first takes ages to connect to it and after it lets me to the next dialog with the test page printing, the printer prints fine but printing queue gives error status after a while so I assume it just timeouts. Same thing happens when I try to print something else. So printing works but according to Windows the print failed. So to me this sounds like Windows isn't getting some information back from the printer.

We have multiple printers we want to connect to the server (which is not in the intranet) so I'm using custom port for each that forwards to each printer's port 631. I suspect this is the reason why the errors come up but I'm not sure how.

I'm more used to dealing with Linux servers so all the Windows Server newbie mistakes are completely plausible in this case.